# Why is this C# question historical locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, historical-lock

I ran across [this C# question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp) as part of a discussion in SOCVR about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307467/what-does-var-mean-in-c) that was originally marked as a duplicate.

The question does not seem to be off-topic, which means a historical lock seems inappropriate. Per [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41479/timeline), a former moderator closed it (with the outdated "not constructive" reason) and another former mod reopened it and then locked it.

1. Is this question actually off-topic?
2. If not, why can we not just duplicate flag one?

Comment: Going by "I wondered what people's opinions were on the appropriate uses of type inference via var?" I would gather that right now it would attract opinion based close votes. It may not be off topic (it's about a feature of a language), but it wouldn't be a questions that should be asked on SO.

Comment: Is there anything more to say about the topic that isn't covered in the 86 answers the question already has? I've voted to close the unlocked one as a duplicate of the locked one.

Comment: @HereticMonkey considering the the later question doesn't ask for opinions "What does “var” mean in C#?" rather than "opinions were on the appropriate uses of type inference via var" I would say that one isn't a duplicate of the other.

Comment: @Braiam That's certainly a valid opinion to hold. Feel free to not vote to close as duplicates.

Comment: From what I can see from the timeline on the locked post (including deleted comments, etc...) it does appear this post was somewhat controversial even in May 2010 regarding its suitability for the site and was thrashed out in comments... it appears no-one (from my reading of comments)  could _really_ agree, and so it kept going. Then something in Feb 2013 drew attention to it and that debate started again as well as with it reaching 6 delete votes at one point...

Comment: ... it's that point a user flagged to point out it was heavily linked to and viewed. I'd guess the mod thought about that and decided giving the goings on with the other disagreements in comments (the history of the post - plus the building number of delete votes), that it was indeed off-topic but nothing would be gained by letting it get deleted, so hence a historic lock.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me, this question seems primarily opinion based.

It contains a lot of information, but the question, in essence, seems to just be this phrase:

> I wondered what people's opinions were on the appropriate uses of type inference via var?

Also, answers seem to indicate personal preference on code clarity, with disagreement in the comments, indicating the question is actually opinion-based. And it has attracted a lot of meh/bad answers, many of which are deleted.

I think the current status for the question (historical lock) is just fine. It's a useful elaboration and list of opinions on `var`, but not an acceptable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to say. You could remove everything else from the question apart from that sentence, which means the question should have been closed as POB and deleted. Because there's a value in the answers it got historical lock.

Comment: @Dharman why not move those answers to a more deserving question?

Comment: @braiam Feel free to do so. Bear in mind that most answers are only opinions, so they would not fit to any on-topic question anymore.

Comment: Perhaps just *edit the question* to remove the phrase seeming to solicit opinions?

Comment: @CodyGray That doesn't change that the question asks for opinions, and most answers provide opinions. I think it's fine as-is, there are other questions describing what `var` is without that issue, and the code style one is a relevant discussion, it just doesn't fit SO which required the lock, no need to ruin it.